# Displaying a UserControl inside a WinForm

Tags: c#

I am working on a class library that inherits from Form class and then displays this form inside of a Gui app.  Now I need to change the class library into a `UserControl`.

**How do I go about displaying it inside of a form in another project?**  Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

IFaceForm is the usercontrol inside of the InterfaceLibrary.

```
using InterfaceLibrary;

namespace MxlInterface
{  
    public partial class IFaceConn : Form
    { 
        iFaceForm Interface = new iFaceForm();

        //size of the parent form is 881,514
        //use these variables to change the position of the "Interface Form"
        int xlocation = 0;
        int ylocation = 0;

        public IFaceConn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Interface.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Interface.Location = new Point(xlocation, ylocation);
            //Interface.MdiParent = this;

            Interface.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post any relevant code you may have.

Comment: this.Controls.Add(Interface);

Comment: thanks all, was easier than I thought :)

Comment: Could you guys briefly explain to me why using a UserControl in a class library is more beneficial than using a Form?

Answer (score 4):

You could add it to the form directly by doing something like:

```
MyUserControl myControl = new MyUserControl();
Controls.Add(myControl);
```

It's also often useful to place a `Panel` that can be the placeholder for the user control on your form, and then add the user control to that panel:

```
MyUserControl myControl = new MyUserControl();
myControlWrapperPannel.Controls.Add(myControl;
```